# CXF web services won't work after upgrading to 2.2.10

Tags: java, web-services, upgrade, cxf, openejb

After upgrading OpenEJB from 3.1.2 (uses CXF 2.0.9) to OpenEJB 3.1.3 (uses CXF 2.2.10) CXF-based web-services are broken with the following exception on a server side:

```
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
    WARNING: Interceptor for {http://xxxxxx.com/wsdl}ProInfoMgmtWebService has thrown exception, unwinding now
    java.lang.NullPointerException
     at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:961)
     at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:949)
     at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJInInterceptor.java:183)
     at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJInInterceptor.java:71)
     at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:244)
     at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:110)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.HttpDestination.invoke(HttpDestination.java:123)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.processPOST(CxfWsContainer.java:106)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.onMessage(CxfWsContainer.java:77)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.OpenEJBHttpWsRegistry$ClassLoaderHttpListener.onMessage(OpenEJBHttpWsRegistry.java:117)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.HttpListenerRegistry.onMessage(HttpListenerRegistry.java:43)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.OpenEJBHttpServer.process(OpenEJBHttpServer.java:176)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.OpenEJBHttpServer.processRequest(OpenEJBHttpServer.java:132)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.OpenEJBHttpServer.service(OpenEJBHttpServer.java:78)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.HttpEjbServer.service(HttpEjbServer.java:61)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.ServicePool$2.run(ServicePool.java:91)
     at org.apache.openejb.server.ServicePool$3.run(ServicePool.java:120)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

It seems that it's not OpenEJB problem but CXF-only. What could have changed between CXF 2.0.9 and 2.2.10 to cause this error?

Comment: Have you tried to file an issue report to OpenEJB (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB) ?

Comment: not yet. I don't really want to go that path right away and I know that openejb people are watching this forum...

Comment: @grigory Jean-Louis is typically the guy who does all the web service stuff and is the one who did the upgrade.  Don't think he keeps an eye on stackoverflow.  Might be better to ask on the users list or file a JIRA.

Comment: Thanks! Created OPENEJB-1397 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-1397

Comment: What are your tomcat, windows and jdk versions? There are tested combinations: http://openejb.apache.org/openejb-313.html

Comment: Try to update to 3.1.4 (from Nov 17th)

Comment: @topchef - FYI. This [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3170) seems to have been resolved in 2.3.3 .

Answer (score 1):

There is the related bug [CXF-3170 "NullPointerException in StaxUtils.java:961"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3170) from Dec 6th. It seems to be exactly the same problem and the author know the reason:

> This is due to the way we configure Jetty and CXF in a jetty.xml file, so it our fault so to speak.

You are probably need to ask directly the author of the CXF bug **OR** wait for the next release of CXF where this bug will be fixed and ask OpenEJB developers to upgrade CXF.